# check mergeability of two branches using the github api without creating a PR

Tags: git, github, github-api

Question from my comment here:
[How to check mergeability of a branches using the github api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655340/how-to-check-mergeability-of-a-branches-using-the-github-api)

Is it possible to check the mergeability of two branches using the github API without making a PR? I dont want to trigger anything by creating a PR, even if I immediately delete the PR afterwards.

Comment: I believe you can already compare a feature branch in a diff against its source branch in the GitHub UI.  Also, locally you can use a Git pluging in an IDE like IntelliJ to view diffs of files.

Comment: Using the github API, not the UI or using git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use the [GitHub API compare commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) (which can be used for branches), as I [illustrated here](http://GET%20/repos/:owner/:repo/compare/user1:branchname...user2:branchname).

That will give you a status:

```
  "status": "behind",
  "ahead_by": 1,
  "behind_by": 2,
```

If you see only ahead: the branch will be easily mergeable (fast-forward).
If you see both ahead and behind... there might be conflict, but it is harder to be sure.

Comment: This is the closest you're going to get without making a pull request

Comment: You can also hack it just by using a GET request on the `.../compare/base...feature-branch` and then scrape the resulting HTML for the `Can’t automatically merge.` string. This is obviously very brittle but is a decent way to sniff this out w/o requiring any repo mutation.

Comment: @xanadont Interesting. The compare is the one I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962188/6309?

Comment: @VonC That's via the API. I mean to say, you can use the public web URL that you would normally load in a browser. AFAICT, you can't actually get from the API a definitive `true` or `false` whether a compare has merge conflicts or not. The hacky method I suggested does. But maybe I'm missing something?